# How to create a page with StatusCode 500 and errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

My production server uses the following configuration to prevent error details from being shown:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" />
</system.webServer>
```

I have a page (`a.aspx`) that transfers to (`b.aspx`) when something weird happens (using a `Server.Transfer`). `b.aspx` sets its `StatusCode` to 500. When this status code is set to 500 or 404, the page is not shown. The custom error page from IIS is rendered.

If I don't set a status code, all is well. But now some AJAX will not work, because it thinks `a.aspx` rendered successful.

**How can I indicate to IIS that `b.aspx` is *not* a detailed error page?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like .Net thought about this scenario:

```
Response.StatusCode = 500;
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

Remarks:

> The TrySkipIisCustomErrors property is used only when your application
>   is hosted in IIS 7.0. When running in Classic mode in IIS 7.0 the
>   TrySkipIisCustomErrors property default value is true. When running in
>   Integrated mode, the TrySkipIisCustomErrors property default value is
>   false.

Source:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors.aspx

Don't know how this works in IIS > 7.0.